# JNAerator - using interfaces generated by typedef

Tags: java, c++, jna, jnaerator, bridj

I'm trying to use a generated interface by JNAerator from a typedef instruction, but I can't find a way to do that:

The function in the .h file is:

```
MyClass::Initialize(LPCWSTR path);
```

The header file also includes the original typedef instruction:

```
typedef __nullterminated CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR, *PCWSTR;
```

JNAerator generates:

**Method:**

```
public native int Initialize(LPCWSTR path);
```

**The interface:**

```
/// Undefined type
/// Undefined type
public static interface LPCWSTR {

};
```

**And the classes:**

```
/// C type : WCHAR*
    public Pointer<Short > LPCWSTR() {
        try {
            return (Pointer<Short >)BridJ.getNativeLibrary("dlls").getSymbolPointer("LPCWSTR").as(DefaultParameterizedType.paramType(Pointer.class, Short.class)).get();
        }catch (Throwable $ex$) {
            throw new RuntimeException($ex$);
        }
    }
    /// C type : WCHAR*
    public MainLibrary LPCWSTR(Pointer<Short > LPCWSTR) {
        try {
            {
                BridJ.getNativeLibrary("dlls").getSymbolPointer("LPCWSTR").as(DefaultParameterizedType.paramType(Pointer.class, Short.class)).set(LPCWSTR);
                return this;
            }
        }catch (Throwable $ex$) {
            throw new RuntimeException($ex$);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, I don't know how to instantiate an object `LPCWSTR` using `Pointer` and the `LPCWSTR` interface, using a String, so that I can pass it to the `Initialize` method.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**

I modified the .h file to use `wchar_t*`:

```
MyClass::Initialize(wchar_t* path)
```

JNAerator generated the method like this:

```
public native int Initialize(Pointer<Character > path);
```

So I called it like this:

```
MyClass factory = new MyClass();
Pointer<Character> path = org.bridj.Pointer.pointerToWideCString("dlls");
factory.Initialize(path);
```

The problem is that I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: main.MyClass.Initialize(Lorg/bridj/Pointer;)I
```

at this line:

```
factory.Initialize(path);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `UnsatisfiedLinkError` indicates that your native `Initialize` method was not bound by BridJ.

This binding is done by [CPPObject](http://nativelibs4java.sourceforge.net/bridj/api/development/org/bridj/cpp/CPPObject.html)'s constructor (I assume you got a JNAerated MyClass class that inherits from it), and any failure to bind should result in error logs in your console (in any case, you can increase the logs verbosity with *BRIDJ_VERBOSE=1* environment variable).

Also, please note that your `MyClass` should have a `@Library("mylibrary")` annotation to let it know where to find the appropriate library (*.dll*, *.so* or *.dylib*), or should be an inner class of a class with such an annotation. This is normally the case of JNAerated classes, but if it's not, please report a bug in [NativeLibs4Java's tracker](https://github.com/ochafik/nativelibs4java/issues/new).

Comment: all of the lines above (except the code describing the way i use the classes) are from the JNAerator generated classes. I also checked the @Library annotation and it was ok. I forgot to add the fact that the mentioned exception is thrown at this line: factory.Initialize(path);

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too. zOlive’s response sent me down the right path. I changed the JNAerator library option to match my DLL name (e.g. `-library MyLib MyLib.dll MyLib.h`).  That fixed it for me. There is more info about the library option [here](https://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/wiki/CommandLineOptionsAndEnvironmentVariables).